# Tapestry - Writing a file to webapp directory

Tags: java, file-io, tapestry

I'm trying to write out some xml to a file within a subdirectory of the webapp. Let's say for this case the directory is:

C:\Tapestry\xyz\src\main\webapp\directory1\

How can I get the part of the file path which is C:\Tapestry\xyz\src\main\webapp\ from within one of the java classes? I don't want to hard code it because then it won't be portable.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm skeptical it's a good idea anyway, although it's available as part of the servlet context. Directories within an app aren't guaranteed to be writable (e.g., deployed as a war) or persistent across deploys.

Comment: Thanks Dave. So I suppose the best way is to have some kind of configuration file which specifies where it is best to keep such files? Maybe I need to think about this another way, so I will explain a little more. I have users currently login and create objects (Assignment objects) which I would like to store as .xml files. The xml files can then later be loaded for some other processing, or by (some) other users. Where is best to store these xml files? Currently I have a Configuration.java file with some static finals Strings for the directory where they will go.

Comment: A configuration property would be the best bet, pointing at a directory external to the web app. Better yet, a strategy for saving the files, so you could drop in S3 or whatever. There are any number of ways to set that config property; in web.xml, environment variable, JNDI lookup, etc

Comment: Thanks Dave. I'll go and take a look into some of these options. I think really this answers my question, so if you'd like to make it an answer rather than a comment I can accept it. Thanks for your help, i'll be working on this today and will comment back on how it goes.